# understanding tkinter gui lists

Tags: python, list, tkinter

i found this code from a youtuber's video. I am making my own system very similar to this, and I want to add in one of his features, however, I don't know how he has done it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.messagebox


# ****** GLOBAL VARIABLES ******

objects = []
window = Tk()
window.withdraw()
window.title('Email Storage')

class popupWindow(object):

    loop = False
    attempts = 0

    def __init__(self, master):
        top = self.top = Toplevel(master)
        top.title('Input Password')
        top.geometry('{}x{}'.format(250, 100))
        top.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.l = Label(top, text=" Password: ", font=('Courier', 14), justify=CENTER)
        self.l.pack()
        self.e = Entry(top, show='*', width=30)
        self.e.pack(pady=7)
        self.b = Button(top, text='Submit', command=self.cleanup, font=('Courier', 14))
        self.b.pack()

    def cleanup(self):
        self.value = self.e.get()
        access = 'tim'

        if self.value == access:
            self.loop = True
            self.top.destroy()
            window.deiconify()
        else:
            self.attempts += 1
            if self.attempts == 5:
                window.quit()
            self.e .delete(0, 'end')
            messagebox.showerror('Incorrect Password', 'Incorrect password, attempts remaining: ' + str(5 - self.attempts))

class entity_add:

    def __init__(self, master, n, p, e):
        self.password = p
        self.name = n
        self.email = e
        self.window = master

    def write(self):
        f = open('emails.txt', "a")
        n = self.name
        e = self.email
        p = self.password

        encryptedN = ""
        encryptedE = ""
        encryptedP = ""
        for letter in n:
            if letter == ' ':
                encryptedN += ' '
            else:
                encryptedN += chr(ord(letter) + 5)

        for letter in e:
            if letter == ' ':
                encryptedE += ' '
            else:
                encryptedE += chr(ord(letter) + 5)

        for letter in p:
            if letter == ' ':
                encryptedP += ' '
            else:
                encryptedP += chr(ord(letter) + 5)

        f.write(encryptedN + ',' + encryptedE + ',' + encryptedP + ', \n')
        f.close()


class entity_display:

    def __init__(self, master, n, e, p, i):
        self.password = p
        self.name = n
        self.email = e
        self.window = master
        self.i = i

        dencryptedN = ""
        dencryptedE = ""
        dencryptedP = ""
        for letter in self.name:
            if letter == ' ':
                dencryptedN += ' '
            else:
                dencryptedN += chr(ord(letter) - 5)

        for letter in self.email:
            if letter == ' ':
                dencryptedE += ' '
            else:
                dencryptedE += chr(ord(letter) - 5)

        for letter in self.password:
            if letter == ' ':
                dencryptedP += ' '
            else:
                dencryptedP += chr(ord(letter) - 5)

        self.label_name = Label(self.window, text=dencryptedN, font=('Courier', 14))
        self.label_email = Label(self.window, text=dencryptedE, font=('Courier', 14))
        self.label_pass = Label(self.window, text=dencryptedP, font=('Courier', 14))
        self.deleteButton = Button(self.window, text='X', fg='red', command=self.delete)

    def display(self):
        self.label_name.grid(row=6 + self.i, sticky=W)
        self.label_email.grid(row=6 + self.i, column=1)
        self.label_pass.grid(row=6 + self.i, column=2, sticky=E)
        self.deleteButton.grid(row=6 + self.i, column=3, sticky=E)

    def delete(self):
        answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('Delete', 'Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')

        if answer == 'yes':
            for i in objects:
                i.destroy()

            f = open('emails.txt', 'r')
            lines = f.readlines()
            f.close()

            f = open('emails.txt', "w")
            count = 0

            for line in lines:
                if count != self.i:
                    f.write(line)
                    count += 1

            f.close()
            readfile()

    def destroy(self):
        self.label_name.destroy()
        self.label_email.destroy()
        self.label_pass.destroy()
        self.deleteButton.destroy()


# ******* FUNCTIONS *********


def onsubmit():
    m = email.get()
    p = password.get()
    n = name.get()
    e = entity_add(window, n, p, m)
    e.write()
    name.delete(0, 'end')
    email.delete(0, 'end')
    password.delete(0, 'end')
    messagebox.showinfo('Added Entity', 'Successfully Added, \n' + 'Name: ' + n + '\nEmail: ' + m + '\nPassword: ' + p)
    readfile()


def clearfile():
    f = open('emails.txt', "w")
    f.close()


def readfile():
    f = open('emails.txt', 'r')
    count = 0

    for line in f:
        entityList = line.split(',')
        e = entity_display(window, entityList[0], entityList[1], entityList[2], count)
        objects.append(e)
        e.display()
        count += 1
    f.close()


# ******* GRAPHICS *********

m = popupWindow(window)

entity_label = Label(window, text='Add Entity', font=('Courier', 18))
name_label = Label(window, text='Name: ', font=('Courier', 14))
email_label = Label(window, text='Email: ', font=('Courier', 14))
pass_label = Label(window, text='Password: ', font=('Courier', 14))
name = Entry(window, font=('Courier', 14))
email = Entry(window, font=('Courier', 14))
password = Entry(window, show='*', font=('Courier', 14))
submit = Button(window, text='Add Email', command=onsubmit, font=('Courier', 14))

entity_label.grid(columnspan=3, row=0)
name_label.grid(row=1, sticky=E, padx=3)
email_label.grid(row=2, sticky=E, padx=3)
pass_label.grid(row=3, sticky=E, padx=3)

name.grid(columnspan=3, row=1, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=W)
email.grid(columnspan=3, row=2, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=W)
password.grid(columnspan=3, row=3, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=W)

submit.grid(columnspan=3, pady=4)

name_label2 = Label(window, text='Name: ', font=('Courier', 14))
email_label2 = Label(window, text='Email: ', font=('Courier', 14))
pass_label2 = Label(window, text='Password: ', font=('Courier', 14))

name_label2.grid(row=5)
email_label2.grid(row=5, column=1)
pass_label2.grid(row=5, column=2)

readfile()

window.mainloop()
```

If you run this (the password is "tim"), you will see that when you input a name, email and password, it gets added to a visible list. I want to add something like this to my own code, but I'm not sure what part causes this. Please give the snippet of code if you know it. Thanks, Tf0R24

Comment: This is too much code. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve] by removing functions and code that isn't strictly necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite a long process, but I'll walk you through it:

When you press the "Add Email" button

```
submit = Button(window, text='Add Email', command=onsubmit, font=('Courier', 14))
```

It calls the function `onsubmit()`.
In this function, it retrieves the values from the entry fields:

```
m = email.get()
p = password.get()
n = name.get()
```

and then creates an instance of their `entity_add` class, passing it the entry values:

```
e = entity_add(window, n, p, m)
```

When initiated, this class just stores those values as its own attributes:

```
    def __init__(self, master, n, p, e):
        self.password = p
        self.name = n
        self.email = e
        self.window = master
```

Back in the `onsubmit()` function, the `.write()` method of the `entity_add` class that was just initiated is called:

```
e.write()
```

This code basically just encodes and writes the values to the emails.txt file in a csv format:

```
def write(self):
    f = open('emails.txt', "a")
    n = self.name
    e = self.email
    p = self.password

    encryptedN = ""
    encryptedE = ""
    encryptedP = ""
    for letter in n:
        if letter == ' ':
            encryptedN += ' '
        else:
            encryptedN += chr(ord(letter) + 5)

    for letter in e:
        if letter == ' ':
            encryptedE += ' '
        else:
            encryptedE += chr(ord(letter) + 5)

    for letter in p:
        if letter == ' ':
            encryptedP += ' '
        else:
            encryptedP += chr(ord(letter) + 5)

    f.write(encryptedN + ',' + encryptedE + ',' + encryptedP + ', \n')
    f.close()
```

At the end of the `onsubmit()` function, the `readfile()` function is called:

```
readfile()
```

This function basically reads the encoded values in the emails.txt file and creates `entity_display` class instances for each line, also calling their `.display()` method:

```
def readfile():
    f = open('emails.txt', 'r')
    count = 0

    for line in f:
        entityList = line.split(',')
        e = entity_display(window, entityList[0], entityList[1], entityList[2], count)
        objects.append(e)
        e.display()
        count += 1
    f.close()
```

When initiated, the `entity_display` class decodes the values passed to it and creates a label for each one (plus an "x" button"):

```
def __init__(self, master, n, e, p, i):
    self.password = p
    self.name = n
    self.email = e
    self.window = master
    self.i = i

    dencryptedN = ""
    dencryptedE = ""
    dencryptedP = ""
    for letter in self.name:
        if letter == ' ':
            dencryptedN += ' '
        else:
            dencryptedN += chr(ord(letter) - 5)

    for letter in self.email:
        if letter == ' ':
            dencryptedE += ' '
        else:
            dencryptedE += chr(ord(letter) - 5)

    for letter in self.password:
        if letter == ' ':
            dencryptedP += ' '
        else:
            dencryptedP += chr(ord(letter) - 5)

    self.label_name = Label(self.window, text=dencryptedN, font=('Courier', 14))
    self.label_email = Label(self.window, text=dencryptedE, font=('Courier', 14))
    self.label_pass = Label(self.window, text=dencryptedP, font=('Courier', 14))
    self.deleteButton = Button(self.window, text='X', fg='red', command=self.delete)
```

Finally, following when its `.display()` method is called, the labels are all displayed using the `.grid()` geometry organiser:

```
def display(self):
    self.label_name.grid(row=6 + self.i, sticky=W)
    self.label_email.grid(row=6 + self.i, column=1)
    self.label_pass.grid(row=6 + self.i, column=2, sticky=E)
    self.deleteButton.grid(row=6 + self.i, column=3, sticky=E)
```

I'm sorry that it is not just a small snippet of code in your example; It is made much more complicated by the fact that they wants to read and write everything to the emails.txt file.

I hope this helps you anyway, I spent a long time looking through the example code and writing this answer.